# MongoDB - Why can't compiled Func<> with function call be used with MongoQueryable?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda

I'm trying to write a generic search function for MongoDB.  I put together a Func<> using a method that accepts the target of the lambda and returns back the value of the named property for that target.

```
case QueryType.BetweenExclusive:
    if (values.Length < 2)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(values),
            "Must supply at least two values for Between comparisons.");
    var ve1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(values[0].ToString());
    var ve2 = DateTimeOffset.Parse(values[1].ToString());

    exp =
        x =>
            GetDateTimeOffset(x, field) > ve1 &&
            GetDateTimeOffset(x, field) < ve2;

    filter = exp.Compile();

    break;
```

`GetDateOffset` is defined as:

```
    public DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(PageHitDE x, string field)
    {
        return x.GetValue<DateTimeOffset>(field, new object[0], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
```

Finally, the `GetValue` extension method is defined in [https://github.com/sharpninja/GenericExtensionMethods/blob/master/ReflectionExtensions.cs].

The compiled Func<> is used like this:

```
results.AddRange(_proxy.Get<PageHitDE>(x => filter(x)));
```

`results` is an IList defined elsewhere.  Get<> is define as:

```
    public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
    {
        String collectionName = typeof(T).Name;
        IMongoCollection<T> collection = Database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        return MongoQueryable.Where(collection.AsQueryable(), predicate).AsQueryable();
    }
```

I really, really, really need to get this working.  I don't understand why a compiled function would not be acceptable to MongoQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

*`I don't understand why a compiled function would not be acceptable to MongoQueryable.`*

What happens behind the scene is Mongo Driver will use `IQueryProvider`  to generate a `BsonDocument` to be sent to your Mongo Server  for execution. 
So Mongo will have  a set of predefined rules on how every Linq operator will be transformed to `BsonDocument` but since  you send `Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate`  Mongo driver can't interpret this because it does't know what  the predicate do exactly.